# Are community wiki posts allowed in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I recently set up Stack Overflow for Teams and I think it will be a great place to store some company specific information. Some of that information may change over time though; it would be great if future users could easily edit the answers I write today.

This seems like exactly what a community wiki question is for but I don't see that option when answering a question. Is that available for Teams?

Comment: That doesn't look like it is exposed in the UI and if I fiddle with what gets posted to inject a "communitymode"=true nothing happens so I assume that got discarded. Needs a dev to confirm. Well, there we are ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Teams, we do not have community wikis.

If someone leaves your Team, their questions and answers will stay in place and *anyone* on your Team will be able to edit their posts moving forward.

The scenario you're describing is common, especially in company-related Teams. That's why people should be able to make changes when they can't get hold of the original author anymore.

On top of that, if you see questions that remained without an accepted answer after people left, any Teams admin can accept answers on their behalf if they think that helps your SO Team.